# My Shopping Cart python code keep printing even if there a invalid sequence

Tags: python

The problem is that my code should not print menu option if there is a invalid character used that isn't in the option. But when it test my code it does that and I am confused beyond belief on how to fix it! Can some one point me in right direction?

My code is below

```
class ItemToPurchase:

    def __init__(self, item_name='none', item_description='none', item_price=0, item_quantity=0):
        self.item_name = item_name
        self.item_description = item_description
        self.item_price = item_price
        self.item_quantity = item_quantity

    def print_item_description(self):
        print(f'{self.item_name}: {self.item_description}')


class ShoppingCart:
    def __init__(self, customer_name='none', current_date='January 1, 2016', cart_items=None):
        if cart_items is None:
            cart_items = []
        self.customer_name = customer_name
        self.current_date = current_date
        self.cart_items = cart_items

    def add_item(self, purchased_item):
        self.cart_items.append(purchased_item)

    def remove_item(self, target_item):
        for stuff in self.cart_items:
            if stuff.item_name == target_item:
                self.cart_items.remove(stuff)
            else:
                print('Item not found in cart. Nothing modified.')

    def modify_item(self, item_modify):
        for stuff in self.cart_items:
            if stuff.item.item_name == item_modify.item_name:
                stuff.item_quantity = item_modify.item_quantity
                break
        else:
            print('Item not found in cart. Nothing modified')

    def get_num_items_in_cart(self):
        number_of_items = sum(stuff.item_quantity for stuff in self.cart_items)
        return number_of_items

    def get_cost_of_cart(self):
        cart_cost = 0
        for cart_item in self.cart_items:
            cost_of_item = cart_item.item_price * cart_item.item_quantity
            cart_cost += cost_of_item

        return cart_cost

    def print_total(self):
        print(f"{self.customer_name}'s Shopping Cart - {self.current_date}")
        print("Number of Items: ", self.get_num_items_in_cart())

        if len(self.cart_items) == 0:
            print("SHOPPING CART IS EMPTY")
        else:
            for stuff in self.cart_items:
                stuff.print_item_cost()
                total = stuff.item_price * stuff.item_quantity
                print(f'{stuff.item_name} {stuff.item_quantity} @ ${stuff.item_price} = ${total}')
            print(f"{self.get_cost_of_cart()}")

    def print_description(self):
        print(f"{self.customer_name}'s Shopping Cart - {self.current_date}\nItem Descriptions")
        for stuff in self.cart_items:
            print(f"{stuff.item_name}: {stuff.item_description}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    name_of_customer = input("Enter customer's name:\n")
    date_of_today = input("Enter today's date:\n")
    print(f"\nCustomer name: {name_of_customer}")
    print(f"Today's date: {date_of_today}\n")
    s_cart = ShoppingCart(name_of_customer, date_of_today)


    def print_menu(shop_cart):
        user_option = ''
        while user_option not in ['a', 'r', 'c', 'i', 'o', 'q']:
            print("MENU")
            print('a - Add item to cart')
            print('r - Remove item from cart')
            print('c - Change item quantity')
            print("i - Output items' descriptions")
            print("o - Output shopping cart")
            print("q - Quit\n")

            user_option = input("Choose an option:\n")

        if user_option == 'a':
            print("ADD ITEM TO CART")
            added_item_name = input("Enter the item name:\n")
            added_description = input("Enter the item description:\n")
            added_item_price = int(input('Enter the item price:\n'))
            added_item_quantity = int(input("Enter the item quantity:\n"))

            new_item = ItemToPurchase(added_item_name, added_description, added_item_price, added_item_quantity)
            shop_cart.add_item(new_item)

        elif user_option == 'r':
            remove_item_name = input("Enter name of item to remove:")
            shop_cart.remove_item(remove_item_name)
        elif user_option == 'c':
            changed_name = input("Enter the item name:\n")
            change_quantity = int(input("Enter the new quantity"))
            changed_item = ItemToPurchase(changed_name, '', 0, change_quantity)
            shop_cart.modify_item(changed_item)
        elif user_option == 'i':
            shop_cart.print_description()
        elif user_option == 'o':
            shop_cart.print_total()
        elif user_option == 'q':
            quit()

    print_menu(s_cart)
```

**This the input I put in**
John John
Febuary 1, 2016
o
q

**and was looking for:**
Enter customer's name:
Enter today's daye:

Customer Name: John John
Today's Date: Febuary 1, 2016
MENU
a - Add item to cart
r - Remove item from cart
c - Change item quantity
i - Output items' descriptions
o - Output shopping cart
q - Quit

Choose an option:
Choose an option:
Choose an option:

**What I got from input**
Enter customer's name:
Enter today's date:

Customer name: John Doe
Today's date: February 1, 2016

MENU
a - Add item to cart
r - Remove item from cart
c - Change item quantity
i - Output items' descriptions
o - Output shopping cart
q - Quit

Choose an option:
MENU
a - Add item to cart
r - Remove item from cart
c - Change item quantity
i - Output items' descriptions
o - Output shopping cart
q - Quit

Choose an option:
MENU
a - Add item to cart
r - Remove item from cart
c - Change item quantity
i - Output items' descriptions
o - Output shopping cart
q - Quit

Choose an option:

Comment: But "o" and "q" are both valid input options.  Why did you expect them to be invalid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that your code should not print menu option if there is an invalid character used. Let's look at what happens in your while loop:

```
def print_menu(shop_cart):
    user_option = ''
    while user_option not in ['a', 'r', 'c', 'i', 'o', 'q']:
        print("MENU")
        print('a - Add item to cart')
        print('r - Remove item from cart')
        print('c - Change item quantity')
        print("i - Output items' descriptions")
        print("o - Output shopping cart")
        print("q - Quit\n")

        user_option = input("Choose an option:\n")
```

After the user input is given it will first be evaluated against the condition `user_option not in ['a', 'r', 'c', 'i', 'o', 'q']`.

If the input is a valid character the while loop will be exited.

If the input, however is an invalid character such as 'x', `user_option not in ['a', 'r', 'c', 'i', 'o', 'q']` will evaluate to TRUE and thus the next line to be executed is inside the loop `print("MENU")`, and then `print('a - Add item to cart')` etc...

If however you only wish to print these menu items the first time, you should move these print statements outside of the loop as follows.

```
def print_menu(shop_cart):
    user_option = ''
    
    print("MENU")
    print('a - Add item to cart')
    print('r - Remove item from cart')
    print('c - Change item quantity')
    print("i - Output items' descriptions")
    print("o - Output shopping cart")
    print("q - Quit\n")

    while user_option not in ['a', 'r', 'c', 'i', 'o', 'q']:

        user_option = input("Choose an option:\n")
```